# Segmentation fault.when using glibc timer

Tags: linux, timer, glibc

```
static timer_t timer;
void timer_handle(union sigval sig)
{
    printf("pthread=%lu ptr=%p\n", pthread_self(), sig.sival_ptr);
}
void x_add_timer(void)
{
    struct sigevent event;
    struct itimerspec ts = {{0, 0}, {0, 10000}};            
    memset(&event, 0, sizeof(event));
    event.sigev_notify = SIGEV_THREAD;
    event.sigev_notify_function = timer_handle;
    timer_create(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &event, &timer);    
    timer_settime(timer, 0, &ts, NULL);     

}
void x_del_timer(void)
{
    timer_delete(timer);
}
int main()
{
    int i;
    struct timespec t = {0, 8000};  
    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        x_add_timer();
        nanosleep(&t, NULL);
        x_del_timer();
    }     
    return 0;
}
```

I am new to Linux programming. I am learning glibc timer. But I meet a strange problem.

I write the code above and using **mips64-octeon-linux-gnu-gcc** to compile.

but Segmentation fault **sometimes** occurs when running on the device

Is there anything wrong in the code?
Thanks a lot.

coredump is

```
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
[New process 16487]
[New process 16443]
[New process 16444]
#0  0x0000005558155568 in main_arena () from /lib64/libc.so.6
```

full backtrace is

```
Thread 3 (process 16444):
#0  0x00000055580c839c in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6
No symbol table info available.
#1  0x0000005558176d38 in do_clone () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
No symbol table info available.
#2  0x0000005558177260 in pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.2 ()
   from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
No symbol table info available.
#3  0x0000005557fb8cdc in timer_helper_thread () from /lib64/librt.so.1
No symbol table info available.
#4  0x0000005558177cec in start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
No symbol table info available.
#5  0x00000055580c83ec in __thread_start () from /lib64/libc.so.6
No symbol table info available.

Thread 2 (process 16443):
#0  0x000000555808f0e4 in nanosleep () from /lib64/libc.so.6
No symbol table info available.
#1  0x000000555808edfc in sleep () from /lib64/libc.so.6
No symbol table info available.
#2  0x0000000120000f54 in main () at hello.c:53
        i = 100
        t = {tv_sec = 0, tv_nsec = 8000}

Thread 1 (process 16487):
#0  0x0000005558155568 in main_arena () from /lib64/libc.so.6
No symbol table info available.
#1  0x0000005557fb8d5c in timer_sigev_thread () from /lib64/librt.so.1
No symbol table info available.
#2  0x0000005558177cec in start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
No symbol table info available.
#3  0x00000055580c83ec in __thread_start () from /lib64/libc.so.6
No symbol table info available.
```

Comment: When i set the timeout to 10ms , it runs OK. what's the differenct between setting timeout 10ms and 10us.

Comment: Did you manage to find exactly where SIGSEGV happend from the core dump? From posted output it's not clear.

Comment: #0  0x0000005558155568 in main_arena () from /lib64/libc.so.6

Comment: Can you recompile with debugging symbols added? I don't see a `main_arena` function in your posted code so it's hard to figure out what's going on. Typically segmentation faults are from over stepping bounds in memory.

Comment: my glibc version is glibc-2.9, maybe my problem is the same as [http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=7094](http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=7094)

Answer (score 0):

You have a clear race condition there.

At higher speeds (shorter sleep time `10us`), your

```
nanosleep(&t, NULL);
```

where t is set to `timespec {0, 8000};`, is returning before the 'timer' fires.

Hence the `x_del_timer()` and `timer_handle()` are happening in wrong order.

Increase the nanosleep() time to reduce this probability.

I wouldn't be surprised if `glibc` support for `OCTEON/mips64` has corner-case issues with timer APIs.